# How to make Pd(111) supercell (√3×√3)R30 via VESTA

Tags: software, crystallography, vesta, avogadro

How to make Pd(111) super-cell (√3×√3)R30  via VESTA or Avogadro software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a pain to do in GUIs like VESTA and Avogadro. In ASE, this can be done just in one line by [`ase.build.fcc111_root`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/build/surface.html#ase.build.fcc111_root):

```
from ase.build import fcc111_root
from ase.visualize import view

atoms = fcc111_root('Pd', root=3, size=(2,2,4), vacuum=5.)
view(atoms)
```

[image]

You can then get the structure file, e.g. in .xyz format, simply by

```
from ase.io import write

write('Pd111.xyz', atoms)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shaun Han

Comment: @RubiAgrawal You can accept the answer if it helps

Comment: Thank you  @Shaun Han                                                                                              Can I ask about R30 notation what does it mean and if not added is the structure different or similar?

Comment: @RubiAgrawal No the R30 notation is associated with root 3. You can check out [this page](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Surface_Science_(Nix)/06%3A_Overlayer_Structures_and_Surface_Diffraction/6.01%3A_Classification_of_Overlayer_Structures) to understand what these notations mean.

Comment: Okey, thank you so much @Shaun Han